# Android AdWhirl AdMob + InMobi strange behavour

Tags: android, adwhirl

I have successfully integrate AdWhirl (v3.0) with AdMob in InMobi.
Now when my app changes ad from let's say AdMob to InMboi strange animation appears (some white backgrounded InMobi animation).

I also have problem with heights of ads. Code snippet here

```
    int diWidth = 320;
    int diHeight = 52;
    float density = mContext.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;

    adWhirlLayout.setMaxWidth((int) (diWidth * density));
    adWhirlLayout.setMaxHeight((int) (diHeight * density));
```

Problem is that this `setMaxHeight` does set height to 52 * density but InMobi uses 48 * density. And because of that there is white space below InMobi ad.

Is there (in AdWhirl) any event that I can handle ad change? Any event for handling animations?

Any ideas for solution of these two problems relating AdWhirl?

10x

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Height Issue

You can use the "custom events" in Adwhirl to get notified when the ad change happens: http://code.google.com/p/adwhirl/wiki/CustomEvents

In your call back you can compare as:

```
if("inmobi".equals(adWhirlLayout.activeRation.name) {
    //set adWhirlLayout height as 48
} else if("admob".equals(adWhirlLayout.activeRation.name) {
    //set adWhirlLayout height as 52
}
```

### Animation Issue

The animation happens because of the Ad change across different networks. Presently there is no API to stop the animation. For future InMobi SDK releases we will consider providing this API and publish the updated InMobiAdapter accordingly.

(Full Disclosure: I work as an engineer with InMobi.)

Comment: That was the best answer I could get. So you still need an email to inmobi helpdesk to solve animation issue or is here ok?

Comment: Hi zmeda,

Here is also okay. As Lohith has provided the answer above, that should resolve your problem. However, we prefer to handle support queries via the helpdesk for issues related to the InMobi Ad Network

(Full Disclosure: I work in the Global Ops team of InMobi)